Terraform cannot move resources due to existing objects already at the intended addresses
My situation:
In my ignorance, I tried to rename Terraform resources like this:
resource "resource_type" "rg" {
  for_each = local.spaces
  name     = "OLD-name-${each.value.space}"
}

to look like this:
resource "resource_type" "rg" {
  for_each = local.spaces
  name     = "NEW-name-${each.value.space}"
}

As you can see, I attempted to change the identifier used for all the resources in this for_each loop. I did not know that I had to move resources to change their identifiers in this way. I thought I could just change the identifier in the code, apply it, and then the resources would be renamed. This is wrong, but I did it anyway.
Result: Terraform attempted to destroy each of the resources, and recreate them with a different name. Destroying failed because of some dependences. But, creating succeeded. So now, out in the cloud and in Terraform state, there are twice as many resources as there are supposed to be -- some under the old name and some under the new:

resource_type.rg["OLD-name-dev"]
resource_type.rg["OLD-name-test"]
resource_type.rg["NEW-name-dev"]
resource_type.rg["NEW-name-test"]

Seeing my mistake, I belatedly tried to move the resources with the moved block so that my CI/CD will execute it:
moved {
  from = resource_type.rg["OLD-name-dev"]
  to   = resource_type.rg["NEW-name-dev"]
}
moved {
  from = resource_type.rg["OLD-name-test"]
  to   = resource_type.rg["NEW-name-test"]
}

This fails because the names are already taken:
Terraform tried to adjust resource instance addresses in the prior state
based on change information recorded in the configuration, but some
adjustments did not succeed due to existing objects already at the intended
addresses:
  - resource_type.rg["OLD-name-dev"] could not move to resource_type.rg["NEW-name-dev"]
  - resource_type.rg["OLD-name-test"] could not move to resource_type.rg["NEW-name-test"]

My question:
In order for the move to complete, I think I need to remove the NEW-name resources. This will free up their identifiers so that the existing resources may take those identifiers. Sound right?
Can I accomplish this with removed blocks?
removed {
  from = resource_type.rg["NEW-name-dev"]
  lifecycle {
    destroy = true
  }
}
removed {
  from = resource_type.rg["NEW-name-test"]
  lifecycle {
    destroy = true
  }
}

It seems to me that these blocks could free up the identifiers I need. But there's something that has me confused:
Can I both remove and move the same identifier in the same codebase? Or will these two actions conflict? Or, might they execute as intended the first time, then conflict the second time they are run? The removal on the first run will be legit but the second time would be a removal of a valid resource, post-rename.
Is there some other way to tell Terraform "move these for real, overwriting the names"?

Do the old resource still exist?

Yes they do. Terraform was unable to delete them. Which is perfect actually. I'd prefer to keep and rename the old resources.

I guess in that case you could just use terraform state rm to remove the new ones and then use the moved block as you intended.

Because the terraform is run in the CI/CD pipeline, it's not easy for me to directly access these resources via my local terraform command line. I was hoping there would be a way to do it in code.

I agree, but it's a very specific issue which I would even argue is not supposed to happen inside the CI/CD pipeline. The moved block can be used to run the first apply and then removed afterwards.

From what I understand of the situation, I think there are two possible resolutions here:

Destroy the ones named "OLD" and keep the ones named "NEW".
Destroy the ones named "NEW" and keep the ones named "OLD".

Due to how your configuration is written -- with the "desired state" setting things to "NEW" -- I expect Terraform is proposing the first option. The warning you shared explains that moving the "OLD" objects isn't possible, and so Terraform is presumably also proposing to delete those objects.
To achieve the second option without changing your configuration, you'll need to take some manual steps:

Tell Terraform to "forget" the two "NEW" objects, using:

terraform state rm 'resource_type.rg["NEW-name-dev"]'
terraform state rm 'resource_type.rg["NEW-name-test"]'


Manually delete the corresponding objects from the remote system.

Run terraform plan to verify that Terraform should now report that the old keys have moved to the new keys, as you wanted.


If you'd prefer to not manually remove objects from the state in this way, a variation on this would be to edit your configuration back to the old form (using the "OLD" keys), and then plan and apply as normal. Terraform will notice that the "NEW" keys are not in the desired state and propose to delete the corresponding objects. If you apply that plan then you'll reach the same state as the end of step 2 in the above list, and so you can then switch back to your newer configuration (with the moved blocks) and perform step 3.
